# How to redirect user to home page with his ID after authentication using Node.js and Passport?

Tags: node.js, authentication, routes, passport.js

i have just started learning node.js so go easy on me :P

I'm using passport to autenticate a user.
The user needs to be redirected to his home page with his ID as a URL parameter after successful authentication, for example:

```
 /home?id=325346546
```

Here is a part of my routes.js

```
    // process the login form
    app.post('/', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect : '/home?id='+req.user._id, //error because 'req' isn't declared
        failureRedirect : '/',
        failureFlash : true
    }));
```

this is my idea, i want to pass the id as parameter to the URL.

I have tried putting a

```
function(req, res) {
}
```

but it didn't work.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check the [documentation](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/) on how to implement a custom callback.

Comment: And Ben, do i need to add "failureFlash : true" to my answer for the flash messages?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to pass it as an option before the callback. `app.post('/', passport.authenticate('local-login', {failureFlash:true}, function(req, res, next) {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ben i got it working, so to anwser my own question here is the complete code:

```
    // process the login form
    app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
      passport.authenticate('local-login', {failureFlash:true}, function(err, user, info) {
       if (err) { return next(err); }
       if (!user) { return res.redirect('/'); }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
       return res.redirect('/home?id=' + user._id);
     });
    })(req, res, next);
    });
```